# ASP.NET Core MVC : developed role-based authorization

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-identity

As I mentioned in the title, I am developing a program on the ASP.NET Core MVC platform. I use `IdentityUser` and `IdentityRole` when authorizing in my project.

As you know, when authorizing in this type of authorization, authorization is assigned to the action by opening tags like `[Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]` on the actions.

But I develop this process further and I have a table with `RoleId` (string), `ControllerName` (string), `MethodName` (string) and `State` (bool) columns that holds the action methods that the roles are authorized for.

While the program is debugging, it will review this table and according to the id of the role to which the user is connected, it will determine which of the actions in the controller from this table is authorized to access and accordingly redirect it to the `AccessDenied` page or enter the page.

I would be happy if someone can help me with this. Thanks in advance, good forums.

I created two classes `AuthorizationService` and `AuthorizationMiddleware` and placed the necessary code in these classes. I injected these classes into the program in the `program.cs` file, but I get errors.

------------------------Edit---------------------

```
    public class CustomAuthorizeAttribute : Attribute, IAuthorizationFilter
    {
        QlabContext _dbContext = new QlabContext();
        private readonly RoleManager<IdentityRole> _roleManager;
        private readonly UserManager<IdentityUser> _userManager;

        public CustomAuthorizeAttribute(RoleManager<IdentityRole> roleManager, UserManager<IdentityUser> userManager)
        {
            _roleManager = roleManager;
            _userManager = userManager;
        }

        public async void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationFilterContext context)
        {
            string request_controller = context.HttpContext.GetRouteData().Values["controller"].ToString();
            string request_method = context.HttpContext.GetRouteData().Values["Action"].ToString();
            bool state = false; //Initial a flag to indicate pass authorize or not

            var roleMethod = _dbContext.AspNetRoleMethods.Where(w => w.ControllerName == request_controller && w.MethodName == request_method).ToList();
            var userName = context.HttpContext.User.Identity.Name;


            if (context.HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                // Giriş yapmış kullanıcının kimliğini alın
                var user = await getUserByName(userName);

                // Kullanıcının rolünü alın
                var userRoles = await getRoleList(user);

                foreach (var roles in userRoles)
                {
                    foreach (var item in roleMethod)
                    {
                        string roleName = getRoleNameById(item.RoleId);

                        if (roles == roleName && request_controller == item.ControllerName && request_method == item.MethodName)
                        {
                            state = item.State;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }

                if (state) //if ture ,just continue, pass authorize
                {
                    return;
                }
                else       //if false ,return a 401 result.
                {
                    context.Result = new UnauthorizedResult();
                    context.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized;
                    return;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                context.Result = new JsonResult(new { message = "Kullanıcı Doğrulanamadı" }) { StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status403Forbidden };
                return;
            }
        }

        public async Task<IList<string>> getRoleList(IdentityUser user)
        {
            return await _userManager.GetRolesAsync(user);
        }

        public string getRoleNameById(string roleId)
        {
            var role = _roleManager.Roles.Where(w => w.Id == roleId).FirstOrDefault();
            return role.Name;
        }

        public async Task<IdentityUser> getUserByName(string userName)
        {
            return await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(userName);
        }
    }
```

I updated the structure like this. My only problem now is in case the user logs in without authorization;

```
  else //if false ,return a 401 result.
  {
      context.Result = new UnauthorizedResult();
      context.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized;
      return;
  }
```

In the above condition, I need to redirect to the AccessDenied page that I defined in program.cs. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you create a custom AuthorizeAttribute in ASP.NET Core?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31464359/how-do-you-create-a-custom-authorizeattribute-in-asp-net-core)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Why do you want to replace roles? It matters, because you can probably use one of the built-in mechanisms like [Claims](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/claims?view=aspnetcore-7.0) or [Policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/policies?view=aspnetcore-7.0) authorization. Or you can just keep using Role authorization: the actual roles are assigned when the user logs in, which means you can change the assignments dynamically. They're certainly not hard-coded

Comment: What you describe is the worst possible option though, because not only will you have to specify *every* controller and action for every user, but all permissions will become invalid when you inevitably change a name. *All* systems (including file systems and OSs) have a way of abstracting authorizations, eg by assigning permissions to groups or roles, creating and assigning specific privileges to users, or both.

Answer (score -1):

You could make a CustomAuthorizeAttribute and use SqlReader to achieve this. Try following:
A table "roleSettings" in Databse "UserAuth3"
[image]

CustomAuthorizeAttribute.cs

```
    public class CustomAuthorizeAttribute : Attribute, IAuthorizationFilter
    {
        public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationFilterContext context)
        {
            //Get role,controller,method from request context
            var userRole = context.HttpContext.User.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.Role);
            string request_controller = context.HttpContext.GetRouteData().Values["controller"].ToString();
            string request_method = context.HttpContext.GetRouteData().Values["Action"].ToString();
            
            bool state = false; //Initial a flag to indicate pass authorize or not


            //use Sqlconnection to read the Table "UserAuth3"
            string connectionString = "Server=192.168.2.68;Database=UserAuth3;User Id=sa;Password=xxxxxx;";
            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                connection.Open();

                string sql = "SELECT * FROM roleSettings";   //read table "roleSettings"
                using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection))
                {
                    using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        while (reader.Read())  //read the table line by line, reader.GetString(1) means second row.
                        {
                            if (reader.GetString(1) == userRole && reader.GetString(2) == request_controller && reader.GetString(3) == request_method) 
                            {
                                state = reader.GetBoolean(4);  //when find the same role/controller/method line, set the state flag.
                                break;
                            }                          
                        }
                    }
                }

                connection.Close();
            }

            if (state) //if ture ,just continue, pass authorize
            {
                return; 
            }
            else       //if false ,return a 401 result.
            {
                context.Result = new JsonResult(new { message = "Access Denied" }) { StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status401Unauthorized };
                return;
            }
        }
    }
```

Add the Attribute at top of Controller

```
    [CustomAuthorize]
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
       ...
```

Register a user and assign an "Admin" role.

```
                var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, Input.Password);

                await _roleManager.CreateAsync(new IdentityRole("Admin"));
                await _userManager.AddToRoleAsync(user, "Admin");
```

Test
[image]

-------------------------Update of rolemangager usage-----------
When using the rolemanager,you will need to add IdentityRole to service.
"AddDefaultIdentity" pattern

```
builder.Services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>().AddRoles<IdentityRole>()
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
```

"AddIdentity" patern

```
builder.Services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser,IdentityRole>()
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
```

Usage reference :https://procodeguide.com/programming/aspnet-core-identity-roles-authorization/

Comment: Thank you for the valuable information you provided. I applied the code you gave to my project, but since I am working in an Identity structure, I need to inject the RoleManager and UserManager into the class.

I encounter Disposed errors when I use it as follows.

         

RoleManager<IdentityRole> _roleManager = (RoleManager<IdentityRole>)context.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetService(typeof(RoleManager<IdentityRole>));
         UserManager<IdentityUser> _userManager = (UserManager<IdentityUser>)context.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetService(typeof(UserManager<IdentityUser>));

Comment: @ErtuğrulÇİÇEK Well, is there any reason to inject service this way? I update something below the answer maybe help to you.

Comment: I found the problem, my way of calling the Class from the Controller was wrong. After making the necessary arrangements, my code worked. However, in cases where the state status is false, page redirects or Jsonresult response is not displayed. Continues to open the page. I have stated the code I had a problem with my question.

Comment: @ErtuğrulÇİÇEK You could redirect to a page like `context.Result = new RedirectResult("https://www.google.com");`

Comment: context.Result = new RedirectToActionResult("AccessDenied", "Home", null);
return;. He needs to work like this. But it doesn't work.

Comment: `RedirectToActionResut` works in my test as long as you have the "accessDenied" action in the Home controller.